# ROOT functions in upROOT?

Tags: uproot, pyroot

I'm trying to run analysis strictly in Python using upROOT, but I'm finding (unsurprisingly) that I have to build a lot of tools that are already in ROOT. I don't mind doing it, but I want to make sure I don't mess stuff up.

For instance, I have the following for mass squared:

```
m_squared = np.divide(np.multiply(p_squared, g_squared), b_squared)
```

Where "p_squared" is the global momentum magnitude (squared), "g_squared" is inverse gamma squared, and "b_squared" is beta squared.

I also have the following for phi:

```
add_pi = np.hstack(np.where((oX < 0.0) & (oY > 0.0)))
subtract_pi = np.hstack(np.where((oX < 0.0) & (oY < 0.0)))
Phi = np.arctan(np.divide(oY, oX))
Phi[add_pi] = Phi[add_pi] + np.pi
Phi[subtract_pi] = Phi[subtract_pi] - np.pi
```

Where "oX" and "oY" are the x and y origin coordinates for tracks, respectively.

Is there something built into upROOT to do this? Or is this just a PyROOT thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s a module in upROOT called “vector” which works for these purposes; it’s new in uproot4 (running with awkward1.0). Anyone interested can check it out [here](https://github.com/scikit-hep/vector). I’m marking this as solved since this is exactly what I'm looking for, though it should be noted that "vector" is currently in development so it's not yet complete.

Thanks!